# trying to open electron desktop application through browser url

Tags: reactjs, electron, electron-builder

After clicking on the browser URL, it redirects to the Electron desktop application, but it is not navigating to the URL route in the Electron application.

```js
if (process.defaultApp) {
    console.log('inside process default==', process.argv.length)
    if (process.argv.length >= 2) {
        console.log('path.resolve(process.argv[1])===', [path.resolve(process.argv[1])])
        console.log('path.resolve(process.argv[1])===', process.execPath)

      app.setAsDefaultProtocolClient('electronoconnect', process.execPath, [path.resolve(process.argv[1])])
    }
  } else {
    console.log('inside process default else condi')
    app.setAsDefaultProtocolClient('electronoconnect')
  }

app.on("second-instance", (event, commandLine, workingDirectory) => {
    // Someone tried to run a second instance, we should focus our window.
    if (win) {
        if (win.isMinimized()) win.restore();
        if (windowOpened === false) win.show();
        else win.focus();
    }

    const urlArgument = commandLine.find(arg => arg.startsWith('electron-sample://'));
    if (urlArgument) {
        const url = urlArgument.split('electron-sample://')[1];
        console.log('Welcome Back! You arrived from:', url);
        //   win.webContents.send('redirectPath', `You arrived from: ${url}`);
        //   win.webContents.send('redirectPath', `if cond command: ${commandLine}`); 
        let requiredPath = url.split('meeting')[1]
        let redirectPath = `http://localhost:${port}${requiredPath}`;
        win.webContents.send('redirectPath', redirectPath);
        win.webContents.loadURL(redirectPath)
        // win.webContents.executeJavaScript(`console.log('pathhhhh from elc====', '${redirectPath}', '====', '${requiredPath}');`);
        // win.webContents.executeJavaScript(`history.pushState({}, '', '${requiredPath}');`);
    } else {
        console.log('Welcome Back', `You arrived from: ${commandLine.pop().slice(0, -1)}`)
        // win.webContents.send('redirectPath', `else condition: ${commandLine}`)

    }
});
```

In `react app.js`:

```js
const electron = window.require('electron');

useEffect(() => {
    electron.ipcRenderer.on('redirectPath', (event, data) => {
        console.log('redirection path from browser===', data)
        if(data){
            navigate(data)
        }
    });

    electron.ipcRenderer.on('launch', (event, data) => {
        console.log('launch called')
    });

    return () => {
        electron.ipcRenderer.removeListener('redirectPath')
        electron.ipcRenderer.removeListener('launch')
    };
}, []);
```

While running this code, I am getting chunk errors, and the page is not loading in the Electron application.